# What does [M] mean in cambridge dictionary Labels & Codes?

Tags: parts-of-speech

A Cambridge [page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rip#) put an **[M]** in front of the sentence

> The previous owner ripped out the fireplace.

I went through the Cambridge Labels & Codes page, didn't find the explanation of it. Could someone give a hint?

Comment: I can't find it either, and can't guess at the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That defintion was taken from the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary, and it has a set of grammar codes that differs from the Advanced Learner's dictionary that provides the main definition.

I found the [dictionary on google books](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Cambridge_Academic_Content_Dictionary_Re/pqlRO2jdI2gC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PP3&printsec=frontcover)

It has:

> [ M ] A phrasal verb that takes an object which can come before or after the adverb or preposition

My best guess is that it is short for "Multi-word Verb" ([a term that Cambridge uses occasionally](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs)). It's bad that they don't include that in the website.

[image]

Comment: Taking this one step further, I think this is indicating that the example sentence is correct as written, with the object after the preposition of the phrasal verb, and it is also correct with the object before the preposition, as "The previous owner ripped the fireplace out." If my interpretation is correct, it might be helpful to edit an example into the answer.